# Set min-height equal to width

Tags: html, css, height, width

I have a fluid width div which is within another block-level element.

HTML

```
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width:50%;
    min-height: /*equal to width */;
}
```

I want the min-height set equal to the width so that it is a square shape unless there is too much content. At that point, it should expand vertically. Can this be achieved with CSS?

What I've tried:

- Using percentage paddings or margins, but this only sets height, not max--height and pushes the content down.

Comment: Is your `div` contained in the viewport (top level) or is some other block-level element?

Comment: It's within a block level element which has a max-width set so that it gets smaller if the viewport width is less than the max-width.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because padding is relative to an elements width, you can use a pseudo element to force a min height by using `padding-top: 100%;`:

```css
div {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  background: lightGreen;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div></div>

<div>
  div with content. div with content. div with content. div with content. div with content. div with content. div with content. div with content. div with content. div with content. div with content. div with content. div with content. div with content.
  div with content. div with content. div with content. div with content. div with content. div with content.
</div>

<div>
  div with content. div with content.
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, nice. I tried this but the pseudo element added extra space in the div with content. I see adding the float prevents that issue. I'll accept this when it lets me!

Comment: In case anyone uses this with a flexbox child, then you have to set `display: flex;` also on the wrapping element so that the height is inherited by the flexbox child.

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to use [viewport percentage units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths). In this case, `50vw` is 50% of the viewport. If the `div` is a root element and its `width` is relative to the viewport, then this work work as expected. You would otherwise have to calculate the height relative to the viewport for this to work.

For example:

```css
div {
  width: 50vw;
  min-height: 50vw;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question to include the information that this div is within a block level element, so it's width will not necessarily be the same as the viewport.

Comment: @kthornbloom It may be possible to use `calc()` to calculate the value.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Turnip's answer, here's what I ended up using this:

```css
/* Maintain Height While Loading Trick */
figure {
  background: #999;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1;
}
figure:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
  float: left;
}

/* some other CSS that's probably in your project already */
div {
  max-width: 25%;
  margin: 10px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/4000/4000" alt="">
  </figure>
</div>

<h1>Some stuff below the image. Is it jumpy?</h1>
```